# How do I maintain tangent lines in curve with hooks?

Tags: curve-modifier

I am currently using a curve object as a path for a conveyor belt. This conveyor belt passes over a system of stationary rollers, touching each roller at a tangent. I had to draw the curve by trial and error to get the tangents to look ok. The trouble is the the red roller is an adjustable roller - so I need it to be able to revolve around the green roller without ruining the appearance of tangents/tension. The curve is highlighted with an emission shader so you can see it, and how it deforms when the red roller is revolved by an angle. Any suggestions?

Here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dAvja3CvymlsWfMhWe86wSpVroHVzbZX/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, JB.. I think it might help to know what the limits are on the the angle through which the red roller is allowed to rotate about the green roller.

Comment: 90 degrees clockwise from 3 O'clock. Thanks!